# Array types for useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I have two cases in which I use `setState` to set an array of objects. Looks like this:

```
  const [friendList, setFriendList] = useState<any>();

  const _onCompleted = (data: any) => {
    let DATA = data.me.friends.map(
      (item: {
          firstName: string;
          id: number;
          rating: number;
          vehicles: Array<Vehicle>;
          friends: Array<User>;
        
      }) => ({
        id: item.id,
        imageUrl: defaultUrl,
        name: item.firstName,
        rating: item.rating,
        vehicles: [],
        numberOfFriends: item.friends.length,
      }),
    );
    setFriendList(DATA);
  };
```

In case on onComplete, data looks like this:

```
DATA
Array (3)
0 {id: 1, imageUrl: "https://", name: "Bob", rating: 1, vehicles: [], …}
1 {id: 3, imageUrl: "https://", name: "Rhena", rating: 3, vehicles: [], …}
2 {id: 4, imageUrl: "https://", name: "Jack", rating: 4, vehicles: [], …}
```

Currently, I am using `<any>`, which works. However, I do not want to use `any`. I tried  creating custom types:

```
type Friend = {
  id: number,
  imageUrl: string,
  name: string,
  rating?: number,
  //vehicles: item.vehicles,
  vehicles?: any,
  numberOfFriends?: number,
};

type FriendList = {
  friendList: Array<Friend>;
};
```

but when I use it like this `useState<FriendList>();`, I get an error on `setFriendList(DATA);` from `onError` that `Argument of type '{ id: string; imageUrl: string; name: string; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<FriendList | undefined>'.`

Why is this so? The remaining fields in my `Friend` type are option so why do I get this error?

I also tried using `useState<Array<Friend>>();` and `useState([])`but I get the same error.

Comment: Side note: In TypeScript, we usually prefer `Friend[]` over `Array<Friend>;` Just easier on the eye

Comment: DATA is an array of objects right? soo why does FriendList has a friendList property? 

i think doing `let DATA: Friend[] = {...}` will fix it.

Comment: but then how should I modify the useState? @AnuragHazra. You're right, I'm probably making the mistake in friendList

Comment: Okay so try this `const [friendList, setFriendList] = useState<Friend[] | undefined>();` and `setFriendList(DATA);`

Comment: Nope, ```Argument of type '{ id: string; imageUrl: string; name: string; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Friend[] | undefined>'.``` @AnuragHazra

Comment: can you try doing just `setFriendList([{ id: 1, imageUrl: "a", name: "b" }])` just to see if it works or not

Comment: I figured the problem. I had hard-coded a string for the id field when its supposed to be. a number :(

Comment: wow haha sneaky bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seem like your `friendList` is `Friendlist` type which is {friendList: Array} and different with `DATA` is Array. There is 2 way to fix it.

- Change `friendList` to Array: `const [friendList, setFriendList] = useState<Array<Friend>>()` and make sure you set `let DATA: Array<Friend>`
- change the way call setFriendList: `setFriendList({friendList: DATA})`

Update: Prefer way using `Friend[`] instead of `Array<Friend>`:

```
const [friendList, setFriendList] = useState<Friend[]>();

  const _onCompleted = (data: any) => {
    let DATA: Friend[] = data.me.friends.map(
      (item: {
          firstName: string;
          id: number;
          rating: number;
          vehicles: Array<Vehicle>;
          friends: Array<User>;
        
      }) => ({
        id: item.id,
        imageUrl: defaultUrl,
        name: item.firstName,
        rating: item.rating,
        vehicles: [],
        numberOfFriends: item.friends.length,
      }),
    );
    setFriendList(DATA);
  };
```

Comment: I would prefer to use the first. I already tried it but I keep getting ```Argument of type '{ id: string; imageUrl: string; name: string; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Friend[] | undefined>'.
  Type '{ id: string; imageUrl: string; name: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Friend[]'.```

Comment: Make sure you set let `DATA: Array<Friend>`, check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for setting the type -

```
const [friendList, setFriendList] = useState<Array<Friend>>([]);
```

additionally, you can cast the type in case of multiple options in type -

```
setFriendList(DATA as Array<Friend>);
```

Comment: The second option gives me ```Argument of type 'Friend[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<undefined>'.
  Type 'Friend[]' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: undefined): undefined'.ts(2345)```

Comment: while the first one gives me the same error as above

Comment: can you check the DATA var if that has data of array type

Comment: Yup. I printed data on console and added it in the qs

Comment: you do have a default array - useState<Array<Friend>>([]); ?